# Yocto 4 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, operating-system, yocto

I have been trying to install Yocto 4 or 4.1 kirkstone/langdale on RPi but after building and flashing, the RPi fails to boot, it crashes in 2-3 seconds into boot. There are no problems with the SD Card or PSU, I have successfully flashed Yocto 3.1 and it boots no problem.

My bblayer -->

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /local/home/my_user/rpi_builds/langdale/poky/meta \
  /local/home/my_user/rpi_builds/langdale/poky/meta-poky \
  /local/home/my_user/rpi_builds/langdale/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
 /local/home/my_user/rpi_builds/langdale/poky/meta-raspberrypi \
 "
```

Local.conf -->

```
...
    MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi4-64"
    IMAGE_FSTYPES = "tar.xz ext3 rpi-sdimg"
...
```

Command used for flashing -->

```
sudo dd if=core-image-minimal-dev-raspberrypi4-64.rpi-sdimg of=/dev/disk4
```

Can anyone confirm if 4.0+ can run on rpi, I have only been able to find dunfell based tutorials.

This is the 1 sec screen grab before the screen goes dark. (white first, then red part)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BLxN.jpg

Comment: Both poky and RPI raspberry use the same matching branch.

Comment: `the RPi fails to boot, it crashes in 2-3 seconds into boot` What error are you getting? Without proper information no one will be able to help.

Comment: I understand, however there is no error, the screen just goes black, the HDMI output stops, the ACT lights stop blinking, there is an occasional 1 short flash, which from the manual indicated generic boot failure. I haven't been able to find any way to see the logs from sd card itself in a different machine

Comment: I think you need to use a USB-Serial console cable, attach it to Raspberry serial console, use a terminal program on your host machine `minicom` on Linux or `Teraterm` on Windows to see the boot logs. Post them in your question